# When will $l_1$-relaxation give the same answer as the $l_0$ problem?

Tags: optimization, constraints

The $l_0$-relaxation problem 
$$\min_x \Vert x \Vert_0 \text{ subject to Ax = b}$$ 
is non-convex. 
On the other hand, the $l_1$ problem 
$$\min_x \Vert x \Vert_1 \text{ subject to Ax = b}$$ 
is convex. We want to solve the $l_1$ problem in the hope that its solution is the same as the solution to the $l_0$-relaxation problem.

I learned [nullspace property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullspace_property) guarantees the two solutions to be the same.

Are there other theorems that guarantee the agreement?

Comment: spark, coherence, restricted isometry property; see http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/summer2013/slides/Lec03_SparseRecoveryGuarantees.pdf

Comment: @ LinAlg Thank you! This set of slides is really helpful!